# Get use token in a backstage frontend plugin

Tags: backstage

I'm developing a front-end plugin in backstage and need the user data that already logged in.

I can get the `userEntityRef` that is something like `user:default/guest` with the `useApi, identityApiRef` from `@backstage/core-plugin-api`, but can't get the signed token that is in the backstage cookies ( or in the Authorization header of it ). How can I get it without the backend plugin apis?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! It is possible using the `getCredentials` in `identityApiRef` from `@backstage/core-plugin-api`:

```
import { useApi, identityApiRef } from '@backstage/core-plugin-api'

const identityApi = useApi(identityApiRef);
identityApi.getCredentials().then(token => {
    console.log(token)
})
```